# Error unknown type name 'ı'

Tags: c++

No consigo que compile este sencillo programa, me salen decenas de errores:

```
#ıⅽᑯ℮ ˂ıᴑѕᴦ℮аⅿ˃

ı ⅿаı〔〕
❴
    ѕᑯ‎׃‎׃ⅽᴑ ≪ "Hᴑа ⅿᑯᴑ!";
    ᴦ℮ᴦ ⵔ;
❵
```

Compilando con GCC o clang la mayoría de errores que salen son rarísimos y no los había visto nunca, ni siquiera los entiendo; pero entre los errores hay, uno me llama mucho la atención:

> ```
> unknown type name 'ı'
> ```

¿Qué tengo que incluir para que el programa entienda los tipos enteros?, sólo he incluido `˂ıᴑѕᴦ℮аⅿ˃` porque pensé que un programa sencillo no necesita más cabeceras.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> ¿Qué tengo que incluir para que el programa entienda los tipos enteros?, sólo he incluido `˂ıᴑѕᴦ℮аⅿ˃` porque pensé que un programa sencillo no necesita más cabeceras.

No hay que incluir nada, `int` es un tipo fundamental y viene incorporado en el lenguaje; los tipos fundamentales de C++ son:

- `void`.
- `std::nullptr_t`.
- `bool`.
- `signed char`.
- `unsigned char`.
- `char`.
- `wchar_t`.
- `char16_t`.
- `char32_t`.
- `short`.
- `short int`.
- `signed short`.
- `signed short int`.
- `unsigned short`.
- `unsigned short int`.
- `int`.
- `signed`.
- `signed int`.
- `unsigned`.
- `unsigned int`.
- `long`.
- `long int`.
- `signed long`.
- `signed long int`.
- `unsigned long`.
- `unsigned long int`.
- `long long`.
- `long long int`.
- `signed long long`.
- `signed long long int`.
- `unsigned long long`.
- `unsigned long long int`.
- `float`.
- `double`.
- `long double`.

El problema que te has encontrado se debe a que los compiladores que has usado no han entendido el tipo `ı`, que no es el mismo que el tipo `int`. Si quieres que ambos tipos sean equivalentes deberás usar un alias:

```
using ı = int;
```

Pero ese es el menor de tus problemas, lo que te sucede es que los caracteres de tu código no son los que parecen; seguramente has sacado el código de una fotografía y lo has pasado por una [herramienta ROC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconocimiento_%C3%B3ptico_de_caracteres) de baja calidad.

Permíteme ilustrarte:

## [`ı`](http://graphemica.com/%C4%B1)

Es la letra i sin punto del alfabeto latino, cuyo unicode es `U+0131`, sus principales usos se dan en los alfabetos [Azerbaijani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azerbaijani_alphabet), [Kazakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazakh_alphabet) y [Tartar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatar_alphabet) pero también puede ser usada como una variante estilística en otros idiomas al tener mucho parecido con la i.

Es la letra n de notación matemática, cuyo unicode es `U+1D5C7`, su principal uso es como símbolo en ecuaciones, habitualmente ecuaciones que impliquen [valores factoriales](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).

Es la letra t de notación matemática, cuyo unicode es `U+1D5CD`, su principal uso es como símbolo en ecuaciones, habitualmente como substituto de la magnitud de [tiempo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo).

---

Además de los caracteres `ı`, tu código contiene otros caracteres que el compilador no reconoce:

## [`ⅽ`](http://graphemica.com/%E2%85%BD)

Es el [numeral romano](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeraci%C3%B3n_romana) correspondiente al valor [100](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cien), pero en versión pequeña. Su unicode es `U+217D`, su principal uso es para escribir números en notación Romana.

Es la letra l de notación matemática, cuyo unicode es `U+1D695`, su principal uso  es como símbolo en ecuaciones, habitualmente como substituto del [número cuántico azimutal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_cu%C3%A1ntico_azimutal), que es un número cuántico de un orbital atómico que determina su momento angular orbital y describe la forma del orbital, como claramente se puede ver en el siguiente esquema:

[image]

Es la letra  de notación matemática, cuyo unicode es `U+1D5CF`, suele ser usada como el ípsilon minúscula.

## [`ᑯ`](https://graphemica.com/%E1%91%AF)

Es la KO del [silabario indígena canadiense](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silabarios_ind%C3%ADgenas_canadienses), cuyo unicode es `U+146F`.

## [`℮`](https://graphemica.com/%E2%84%AE)

Es el [Signo de estimación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signo_de_estimaci%C3%B3n), cuyo unicode es `U+212E`. Se usa para indicar la cantidad media de producto en un lote de paquetes que no es menor que la especificada en el paquete o que ningún paquete tiene un error por defecto superior al doble del límite establecido.

## [`˂`](https://graphemica.com/%CB%82)

Es un [modificador de espaciado de letra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacing_Modifier_Letters), cuyo unicode es `U+02C2`. Generalmente se usa como modificador para [aspiración](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspiraci%C3%B3n_(fon%C3%A9tica)) o [palatización](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(phonetics)) de fonemas.

## [`ᴑ`](https://graphemica.com/%E1%B4%91)

Es la letra [o tumbada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O), cuyo unicode es `U+1D11`.

## [`ѕ`](https://graphemica.com/%D1%95)

Es la letra [Dze del alfabeto cirílico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%85), cuyo unicode es `U+0455`. Deriva de la letra ligadura stigma (Ϛϛ) que representaba originalmente una ligadura entre una sigma lunar (c) y una tau (τ).

## [`ᴦ`](https://graphemica.com/%E1%B4%A6)

Es la letra [Gamma del alfabeto griego](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%93), cuyo unicode es `U+1D26`. Se usa en matemáticas como símbolo de la [función Gamma](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funci%C3%B3n_gamma), los [Símbolos de Christoffel](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%ADmbolos_de_Christoffel) (relativos a derivadas de vectores y tensores), la [distribución Gamma](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_gamma) en estadística, en [ingeniería eléctrica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingenier%C3%ADa_el%C3%A9ctrica) para identificar el [coeficiente de reflexión](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coeficiente_de_reflexi%C3%B3n) en el estudio de [líneas de transmisión](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADnea_de_transmisi%C3%B3n) y para indicar la concentración superficial de exceso, en química.

## [`а`](https://graphemica.com/%D0%B0)

Es la letra [A del alfabeto cirílico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90) `U+0430`. Proviene directamente de la letra alfa del alfabeto griego. En el alfabeto cirílico antiguo su nombre era azǔ y representaba al número uno.

## [`ⅿ`](https://graphemica.com/%E2%85%BF)

Es el [numeral romano](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeraci%C3%B3n_romana) correspondiente al valor [1000](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil), pero en versión pequeña. Su unicode es `U+217F`.

## [`˃`](https://graphemica.com/%CB%83)

Es un [modificador de espaciado de letra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacing_Modifier_Letters), cuyo unicode es `U+02C3`. Generalmente se usa como modificador para [aspiración](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspiraci%C3%B3n_(fon%C3%A9tica)) o [palatización](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(phonetics)) de fonemas.

## [`〔`](https://graphemica.com/%E3%80%94)

Es el [corchete caparzón de tortuga](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Par%C3%A9ntesis#Corchetes_caparaz%C3%B3n_tortuga) de apertura, cuyo unicode es `U+3014`.

## [`〕`](https://graphemica.com/%E3%80%95)

Es el [corchete caparzón de tortuga](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Par%C3%A9ntesis#Corchetes_caparaz%C3%B3n_tortuga) de cierre, cuyo unicode es `U+3015`.

## [`❴`](https://graphemica.com/%E2%9D%B4)

Es la [llave ornamental](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Par%C3%A9ntesis) de apertura, cuyo unicode es `U+2774`.

## [`‎׃`](https://graphemica.com/%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%D7%83)

Es el [Sof Pasuk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sof_passuk) del alfabeto hebreo, cuyo unicode es `U+05C3`.

## [`≪`](https://graphemica.com/%E2%89%AA)

Es el [doble menor que](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less-than_sign#Double_less-than_sign), cuyo unicode es `U+226A`. Se usa en matemáticas para indicar que un valor es mucho menor que otro.

## [`;`](https://graphemica.com/%CD%BE)

Es el [símbolo de interrogación en alfabeto griego](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark#Greek_question_mark), cuyo unicode es `U+037E`. Apareció más o menos a la vez que el símbolo de interrogación del alfabeto latino. Fue adoptado por el [Eslavo eclesiástico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eslavo_eclesi%C3%A1stico) y eventualmente tomó la forma del punto y coma del alfabeto latino.

## [`❵`](https://graphemica.com/%E2%9D%B5)

Es la [llave ornamental](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Par%C3%A9ntesis) de cierre, cuyo unicode es  `U+2775`.

Comment: Lol la pregunta y respuesta. Btw, doble personalidad? XD